# What is the method for this route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In routes.rb I have

```
 map.resources :groups, :collection => { :find_or_create => :get, :search => :get } do |group|
group.resources :recruitment_periods, :controller => 'groups/recruitment_periods' do |period|
  period.resources :recruits,     :controller => 'groups/recruitment_periods/recruits'
```

if I wanted to redirect to the show action of a specific group,recruit_period, recruit what would the path be?
i.e. `redirect_to groups_recruitment_period_recruit_path(x,y,z)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you almost had it. It looks like it should be:

```
redirect_to group_recruitment_period_recruit_path(x,y,z)
```

No plural on group since you know which one.